# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/WebsocketHome/actions' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I want to communicate with server through websocket, but now the problem is each time i tried to establish connection using `var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/WebsocketHome/actions');` it show "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404" error. I am using jboss v4.0 server. Jar file i am using is "jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec-1.1.3.Final.jar". I tried most probably every solution provided on stackoverflow

Below is the code DeviceWebSocketServer.java

```
package websocket;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/actions")
public class DeviceWebSocketServer
{
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onOpen::" + session.getId());        
    }
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onClose::" +  session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println("onMessage::From=" + session.getId() + " Message=" + message);

        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello Client " + session.getId() + "!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("onError::" + t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>WebsocketHome</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Below is the project structure

[image]

Comment: `404` code is same as `Http 404` so I suggest you to check your address. I'm not sure how jboss works but shouldnt you remove `/WebsocketHome` from address?

Comment: Thanks @SepGH for reply, but my issue is solved, the problem was with jboss as jboss 4 does not support websocket. only jboss version 7 and above support websocket and also apache tomcat 7 and above